# Is there any solution to get next text or element using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
<th scope="row" class="slds-cell-edit cellContainer" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="7585:0">
  <span class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread" data-aura-rendered-by="7620:0">
    <a class="slds-resizable forceContentCompoundFieldsTitleRenderer" data-aura-rendered-by="7588:0" href="javascript:void(0)" data-aura-class="forceContentCompoundFieldsTitleRenderer">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center" data-aura-rendered-by="7589:0">
        <div class="thumbnailCol" data-aura-rendered-by="7590:0">
          <div data-aura-rendered-by="7593:0">
            <!--render facet: 7604:0-->
            <span data-aura-rendered-by="7605:0">
              <lightning-icon data-data-rendering-service-uid="2367" data-aura-rendered-by="7713:0" class="slds-icon_container">
                <span part="boundary">
                  <lightning-primitive-icon lightning-primitiveicon_primitiveicon-host="">
                    <svg lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" class="slds-icon" focusable="false" data-key="" aria-hidden="true">
                      <use lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" xlink:href="/partner/_slds/icons/doctype-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=10.6.0#image"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </lightning-primitive-icon>
                  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Image file</span>
                </span>
              </lightning-icon>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="titleCol truncate" data-aura-rendered-by="7609:0">
          <div data-aura-rendered-by="7612:0" class="forceContentFileTitle" data-aura-class="forceContentFileTitle">
            <div class="slds-truncate" data-aura-rendered-by="7613:0">
              <span class="itemTitle desktop outputTextOverride uiOutputText" data-aura-rendered-by="7616:0" data-aura-class="uiOutputText" title="27BE868-4">27BE868-4</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--render facet: 7617:0-->
        </div>
        <!--render facet: 7618:0-->
      </div>
    </a>
  </span>
</th>

from selenium import webdriver
get_table_row_count = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//table//tbody//tr")
file_count = len(get_table_row_count)
print(file_count)
for item in range(0,file_count):
    try:
       check_file = driver.find_element("xpath","//table//tbody//tr["+str(item+1)+"]//span[text()='Image file']")                                                                     
       print(check_file.text)

    except Exception as e:
           print("PDF")
           pass
```

I have table rows and I have to iterate through table row and I have taken the file count and iterate through rows. If its an image the I check span which is image file or not. But I need to get text of the file which is at the next div "27BE868-4" . Is there any solution to get the text of the next div which is the file name.

Comment: Can you please clarify in you HTML structure, which element are you trying to get?
I don't see any div after file name element
Does file name known for you while you are constructing selector?